# Why, according to Rashi, do the words Aron Ha-Elokim refer to the Urim Ve-Tumim, and not the Aron Ha-Kodesh in I Shmuel 14:18?

Tags: rashi, samuel-shmuel-book-of, ark-aron-kodesh

Rashi comments to the words "Aron Ha-Elokim" in [Shmuel I 14:18](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15843#v=18), saying that these words refer to the Urim Ve-Tumim. Why does Rashi understand these words to be referring to the Urim Ve-Tumim, when simply understood they refer to the Aron Ha-Kodesh? For instance, the Aron Ha-Kodesh is frequently called the Aron Ha-Elokim in [Shmuel I Chapter 5](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15834).

Answer (score 3):

This comment of Rashi is also the view expressed by [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.14.18?lang=he&p2=Malbim_on_I_Samuel.14.18.1&lang2=he) and [Ralbag](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.14.18?lang=he&p2=Ralbag_on_I_Samuel.14.18.1&lang2=he).

It seems to be related to the idea of *inquiring of it* what course of action they should take. This is like Sforno explains to Devarim 18:13 which says:

> **תמים תהיה**: שלם עמו שגם בדרישת העתידות לא תדרוש זולתו אבל תדרוש ע''י נביא או על ידי אורים ותומים:

That was something specifically related to the Urim v'Tumim, and not the Aron HaKodesh.

Comment: This is a nice start, but lacks some info that would make it a full, well-rounded answer. For instance, why are we to assume there isn't a way to "inquire" of the Aron Ha-Kodesh?

Comment: @ezra I’m not sure what you are trying to bring out. The expression, “Aron of G-d” is identical. Rashi clarifies the plain meaning here through the usage expressed in the preceding sentence (פקדו-נא). The OP is asking about the usage here.

Comment: @ezra I think he is making a link to Tamim/Tumim, if I'm understanding correctly. +1, btw